# Visual Studio 2017 Publish doesn't update executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, publish, .net-core-2.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core 2.0 to create a simple console app which I want to run on Windows and macOS.
I'm running VS 2017 version 15.5.4.

I've followed the section: "Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies" from that page.

I make changes to my .cs files and build and the changes are reflected when I debug and then I published the app and it changed it too.

I've now gone back after restarting my laptop and when I build and publish the console application .exe file has the earlier time-stamp and now runs "Hello World" default console app instead of my code.

I've published both Debugs and Release versions and tried creating different profiles and it either comes out as the Hello World App or my first completed publish, but never my latest version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try Cleaning the solution

If this doesn't work, delete the files included in the .vs folder then try rebuilding the project

Comment: That didn't work, but deleting all the bin and obj files and replacing the <project name>.dll file did.

Comment: is the date on your pc correct?
also check the "delete files in destination folder" option in the publish options (if feasible)

Comment: Time on PC is correct, yes. Can't find that as an option.